# How to insert literals automatically in xtext editor

Tags: java, xtext

I am new to xtext. I need to implement the grammar for my below requirement.

```
Book{
   Author
   price
   ...
}
```

I have one class called Book and have fields like Author, price etc.
I can create any number of book instances.
I am creating package for Book in xtext grammar, as soon as I press control+space I am displaying all Book instances and can select required Book instance from dropdown.

now my requirement is when I select any Book instance the corresponding Author name and Price should be inserted with values automatically in xtext editor.
I am storing data in xml.

Eg..

```
Book Book1{
Author : XXXX
Price  : 10$
...
}
```

can any one have a solution how to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like what you are after is [Template proposals](https://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/310_eclipse_support.html#templates).

Comment: hint: template proposals can be "dynamic" as well. see https://nittka.github.io/2010/12/20/Dynamic-template-proposals-in-Xtext.html